# Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'PageController' in type cast? flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

```
onPressed: () async {
    if (pageController != null) {
        if (pageController.page != 3) {
            pageController = await pageController.nextPage(
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                curve: Curves.easeOut) as PageController;
        }
    } else {
        Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(WelcomeScreen.routeName);
    }
},
```

Tried a lot to fix this but end up with nothing, if anyone could help. Thanks.

Comment: Add the complete code

Comment: let's see how you declared your pagecontroller

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the problem has already been solved, if you guys still need the code and explanation, I can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake here

```
pageController = await pageController.nextPage(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    curve: Curves.easeOut) as PageController;
```

The method [`pageController.nextPage`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageController/nextPage.html) does not return a PageController. In fact it returns nothing, it is a void method. And this is why the cast `as PageController` is failing. To put it simple: You cannot convert nothing (void) into something (PageController)

Therefore, you should replace the above line with just

```
await pageController.nextPage(
    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
    curve: Curves.easeOut);
```